# I want to retrieve all posts of a blog without username & password

Tags: api, mobile, third-party-applications

I want to make an android application for my wordpress blog, I want to display there all my blog posts with many options like category wise, date wise, search wise etc...

How Can I retrieve all my blog posts or category wise posts.

Obviously as this will go to each user's mobile, I don't want that I comuunicate with my username & pwd.

Please guide me, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) is what you need. Enable it on your site and use [WordPress XML-RPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) to get information which you need.

Related thread on stackoverflow: [Android XML-RPC library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973231/android-xml-rpc-library)

Comment: but when I call for wp.getPosts method, wordpress returns that there is no such method. I even try by downloading latest wordpress 3.4 beta release.

Comment: @MaulikVora did you enable xml-rpc support at your website?

Comment: yes obviously :)

Comment: It would be a great help if you can post some demo code here? If you have.